# classpath echo returns blank in linux

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I just open file :.bash_profile

**export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin**

Now in command prompt when I fire command : **echo $JAVA_HOME** , It returns me blank.

Am I missing anything? I am trying to set permanent class path in linux.

I have read and follow many similar questions but still no success.

Comment: You can try this solution to set JAVA_HOME: http://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: @xYan - That returns me : ** (gedit:48569): WARNING **: Could not open X display

(gedit:48569): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: So you are remotely connected to the machine? Try using vi instead of gedit or try some of the solutions here: http://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `.bash_profile` are only executed when you start a Login Shell. This is what happens if you, say, log in, or if you run `bash --login`.

The file you're probably looking for is `~/.bashrc`, which is sourced by bash (i.e. executed) every time you start bash. You should put your export there.

Alternatively, on Linux you could put the line `JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin` in the file `/etc/environment`, which should do exactly what you're trying to do (but you need to log out and log in first). This will be system-wide, though.

(for the record, the system-wide `.bashrc` file is `/etc/bash.bashrc`)

**EDIT:** Protip: You can check your environment variables in BASH by typing `export` with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.bash_profile` doesn't read also `.bashrc`, you need to add the above export also to `.bashrc`.

Or, you could add:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

And add everything in `.bashrc` from now on.

Comment: you mean I should add in both files?